# What type of wax plant is this?

Tags: identification

I know it's a wax plant vine; there were quite a few types on Google and the leaves look pretty similar. The leaves are just green with no white spots, just green, on them and the mature leaves are more in a circular shape not a long oval. The 2<sup>nd</sup> photo is of new growth on it. We are doing a regeneration of bushland where people ages ago had a nursery so help would be great.

*Click any photo for full size version*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what location was the plant found in?  Was it growing outdoors or indoors?

Comment: Actually i believe i found it 'Hoya Australis' just in case anyone else has this query, my wax vine didn't have spots on the leaves like the other wax plants so thats what i was lost on.

Answer (score 4):

I found the name. it's a [Waxvine or Common waxflower, *Hoya australis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya_australis). It doesn't have spots on the leaves like the others so took me a while to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [*Hoya obovata*](http://vermonthoyascom.fatcow.com/hoyas-n-z/hoya-obovata/).

I'm not really sure though.